# D3 line chart zoom not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a multi-line D3 chart. I have implemented a zoom, `but when I zoom, I'm not able to zoom to a specific data point on xy location`. Here is a gist of a code that I've developed

```
let xScale = d3
     .scaleUtc()
     .domain([
          d3.min(formattedChartsData, (c) => d3.min(c.values, (v) => v?.x)),
          d3.max(formattedChartsData, (c) => d3.max(c.values, (v) => v?.x)),
     ])
     .nice()
     .range([0, width]);

let yScale = d3
     .scaleLinear()
     .domain([
          d3.min(formattedChartsData, (c) => d3.min(c.values, (v) => v.y)),
          d3.max(formattedChartsData, (c) => d3.max(c.values, (v) => v.y)),
     ])
     .nice()
     .range([height, 0]);

const xAxis = d3
     .axisBottom(xScale)
     .tickFormat(formatTime)
     .tickValues(tickValues);

     const yAxis = d3
     .axisLeft(yScale)
     .tickSize(-boundsWidth)
     .tickValues(yAxisTicks)
     .tickFormat((d) => d3.format(",.2f")(d));

const identifyZoomLevel = async (min, max) => {
     let data = originalTimedilationData.filter((d) => {
          return d.updateTime >= min && d.updateTime <= max;
     });
};

const zoomed = async (event) => {
     const transform = event.transform;
     const rex = transform.rescaleX(xScale);
     const rey = transform.rescaleY(yScale);

     let min = rex.domain()[0];
     let max = rex.domain()[1];
     if (
          compareDates(min, max) === -1 &&
          compareDates(min, latestSettlement.updateTime) === -1
     ) {
          setActiveDateRange(CUSTOMDATERANGE);
          await triggerFilterDataByDateInterval(min, max);

          await identifyZoomLevel(min, max);

          timedilationLines
               .selectAll("path.line")
               .transition()
               .duration(2000)
               .attr("d", (d) => {
                    return setupLines(rex, rey)(d.values);
               });
          g.selectAll("circle.dot")
               .transition()
               .duration(2000)
               .attr("transform", transform);

          timedilationLines
               .selectAll("line")
               .attr("x1", (d) => rex(d.date))
               .attr("y1", (d) => rey(d.loss))
               .attr("x2", (d) => rex(d.date))
               .attr("y2", (d) => rey(d.gain));

          xAxisCaller.transition().duration(2000).call(xAxisGenerator.scale(rex));
          yAxisCaller.transition().duration(2000).call(yAxisGenerator.scale(rey));
     }
};
const debouncedZoomed = debounce(zoomed, 5);

svg
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height)
     .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
     .attr(
          "style",
          "max-width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: visible; font: 10px sans-serif;"
     )
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", `translate(0,${MARGIN.top})`);

svg
     .append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .style("color", "#A0A9B8")
     .style("font-size", "14px")
     .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
     .call(xAxis);

svg
     .append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .style("color", "#A0A9B8")
     .style("font-size", "14px")
     .call(yAxis);

d3.line()
     .x((d) => xScale(d.x))
     .y((d) => yScale(d.y))
     .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

g.selectAll(".timedilation")
     .data(formattedChartsData)
     .enter()
     .append("svg")
     .attr("class", "timedilation")
     .attr("width", width - MARGIN.right)
     .attr("id", (d, i) => `chart-${i}-${d.name}`)
     .append("path")
     .attr("class", "line")
     .attr("d", (d) => line(d.values))
     .style("stroke", (d) => CHARTCOLORMAP[d?.name]);

const zoom = d3
     .zoom()
     .scaleExtent([-0.5, 8])
     .extent([
          [0, 0],
          [width.current, height],
     ])
     .translateExtent([
          [0, 0],
          [width.current, height],
     ])
     .on("zoom", (event) => debouncedZoomed(event));

svg.call(zoom).transition().duration(100);
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If zooming isn't behaving as expected, log the new domains (rex.domain() and rey.domain()) inside the zoomed function to verify that they're being updated correctly. Also, ensure that all graphical elements that depend on these scales are being correctly updated inside this function :)